# JavaFX: Проблема с ссылкой на класс-контроллер

Tags: java, javafx

Доброго времени суток, пишу чат на JavaFX и возникла проблема: Я хочу из главного класса управлять элементами на форме, для этого я создаю поле класса контроллера, объявляю getter для него, а потом при нажатии кнопки в контроллере передаю ссылку этому полю на сам класс, но почему-то при любом действии с компонентами GUI возникает NPE
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делал все вот по этой рекомендации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

clientController - ссылка на сам контроллер в главном классе.
в onMouseClientClicked происходит присваивание ссылки на текущий контроллер полю clientController в главном классе

Очень прошу помощи, так как  отстаю по лабам из-за этого, а все на Swing делают =(

**Класс-контроллер**

```
@FXML
private Button btnCnctToSrv;

@FXML
public Button btnCnct;

@FXML
public TextField tfIP;

@FXML
private TextField tfName;

@FXML
public TextArea taChat;

@FXML
public TextField tfMsg;

@FXML
public Button btnSend;

@FXML

public void showModalWndw(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    try{
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("cnctToSrv.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Connect to Server");
        stage.setMinHeight(25);
        stage.setMinWidth(149);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
        stage.show();


    }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}}

@FXML
public void onMouseClientClicked() throws Exception {
    Stage stage = (Stage) btnCnct.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
    try {


        Client cln = new Client();
        cln.setClientController(this);
        cln.ClientConnect();


    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}

@FXML
public void bntSendClicked(){
    cln.out = new PrintWriter(cln.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    cln.out.println(tfMsg.getText());
    taChat.appendText(tfMsg.getText()+"\n");
}
```

**Главный класс**

```
public class Client  {
public BufferedReader in;
public
PrintWriter out;
public Socket socket;
private ObservableList<String> chatMsgs =         FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public ClientController clientController;



public ObservableList<String> getChatMsgs(){
    return chatMsgs;
}

public void setClientController(ClientController clientController){
    this.clientController = clientController;
}

public void getClientController(ClientController clientController){
    this.clientController = clientController;
}




public void ClientConnect()   {

   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // System.out.println("Введите IP:");

    // String ip = scanner.nextLine();


   try {
        socket = new Socket(clientController.tfIP.getText(),Config.Port);

        clientController.taChat.appendText("Сокет успешно создан\n");

    } catch (Exception e){  e.printStackTrace();  }



    try {
        in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        Resender resender = new Resender();
        resender.start();
        out.println(clientController.tfName.getText());
        out.println("test");


       /* while (!msg.equals("exit")){

            msg = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(msg);

             clientController.tfMsg.appendText(msg);

            if (!msg.isEmpty()) out.println(msg);
        }
        resender.setStop();*/


    } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}
private void close(){
    try {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Потоки не были закрыты.");
    }
}




public class Resender extends Thread {
    private boolean stopped;

    public void setStop(){
        stopped = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            while (!stopped){
                String str = in.readLine();

                //System.out.println(str);
                //clientController.taChat.appendText(str+"\n");
                Platform.runLater(()-> clientController.taChat.appendText(str+"\n"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Ошибка при получении сообщения.");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}


}
```

UPD: Добавил fxml файлы

Использую один и тот же контроллер, так как вызываю модальное окно.

**client.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

  <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"       minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"   xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.ClientController">
  <children>
  <TextArea fx:id="taChat" editable="false" layoutX="154.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="317.0" prefWidth="432.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="tfMsg" layoutX="154.0" layoutY="350.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="341.0" text="text" />
  <Button fx:id="btnSend" layoutX="506.0" layoutY="350.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#bntSendClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Send" />
  <Button fx:id="btnCnctToSrv" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="22.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showModalWndw" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="129.0" text="Connect to server" />
  </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

**cnctToSrv.xfml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="191.0" prefWidth="251.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.ClientController">
  <children>
   <TextField fx:id="tfIP" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="27.0" promptText="Enter the IP" text="127.0.0.1" />
  <TextField fx:id="tfName" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="71.0" promptText="Enter the name" />
   <TextField layoutX="47.0" layoutY="112.0" promptText="Enter the password" />
  <Button fx:id="btnCnct" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="147.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onMouseClientClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" text="Connect" />
 </children>
  <cursor>
  <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
 </cursor>
 </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Добавьте `fxml` файлы, т.к. у меня предположение что оба используют один и тот же контроллер и в этом заключается ошибка.

Comment: Добавил файлы. И да, действительно, использую один класс-контроллер для двух fxml файлов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предпологаю, что проблема в том, что `FXMLLoader` прогрузил два независящих друг от друга контроллера. Вариант решения: в `client.fxml` уберите упоминание контроллера, а в `ClientController.java` замените инициализацию:

```
//Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("client.fxml"));
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource("client.fxml") );
loader.setController( this );
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Comment: Затер контроллеры в обоих fxml файлах, сделал `loader.setController(this);` для каждого окна и все заработало! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Осталось разобраться как сделать так, чтобы GUI работал в отдельном потоке, а то мой класс Client вешает его( там поток запускается, я его реализацию не указывал в коде)

Comment: Эту проблему решил. Вешал бесконечный цикл, который отправлял сообщения на сервер через консольный ввод. Перенес это действие в контроллер для кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам поможет данный код:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("client.fxml"));
MyController myController = (MyController) fxmlLoader.getController();
myController.setScene(scene);
```

Используйте его для загрузки вместо данных строчек:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("client.fxml"));
```